# How to pronounce the letter /r/

Tags: pronunciation

I've always had difficulty pronouncing the letter /r/. Whenever i try to say /r/ it comes out as a gha, a sound similar to the arabic letter غ. Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Hi tzii! Welcome to English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. Somewhat confusingly, there are two Stack Exchange sites that deal with English: this one, and the English Language Learners Stack Exchange. I think your question might get better answers on the English Language Learners site. We'll see what others say. Here's a relevant question from that site, see if the answers there helps you: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40593/which-mouth-form-is-the-close-one-to-pronounce-the-r

Comment: There are many different ways the letter _r_ is pronounced in English. The _r_ in _red_ or in _beer_ are often pronounced differently, and then there is the question of whether one's dialect is _rhotic_ or not.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're using the wrong end of your tongue, then. /r/ in English is pronounced mainly with the _front_ of the tongue, not the back. Apart from that, there are quite a few different ways of pronouncing it, though most include raising the front of the tongue toward the palate, but without making contact.

Comment: English is my first language so i'm not sure if that's necessarily the site i want to go to but i'll check out your link regardless, thanks.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood entirely based on your reference to Arabic sounds. Perhaps it's just a feature of your dialect – as mentioned above, /r/ is one of the sounds that varies the most among speakers in its realization. I think I have read somewhere of dialects of American English with uvular realizations of /r/. But, it might be an individual thing. A speech therapist would probably be familiar with the best teaching methods if you want to "fix" this.

Comment: @sumelic: how about a zero realization of a final _r_(or maybe it's a vowel realization...)? Someone remarked "If you can say _beer can_ in RP, you have just said _bacon_ in Jamaican" ;-)

Comment: Just for clarification I'm British. English is my first language and arabic my second. None of my family or my friends pronounce it this way and I've never met anybody with the same "issue". Also i searched up uvular and that's exactly what my issue is. And as for meeting a speech therapist, I figured that was my best solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you temporarily (or permanently, if things don't work out) replace the R with a different sound that you can comfortably produce, and which people will understand.  Here are a few possibilities:

a Spanish R

a French or German R

an L

Just remember that people from all over the world can be understood pretty well, despite pronouncing the R in their own way.

-- Edit --  Experiment with a variety of foreign-sounding R sounds in your English, and see which one appeals to you most.

I'm not a speech therapist, but my guess is that a good word to try to get a real R in would be something like *fur*.

Comment: From what I understand, the OP is pretty much already using a French or German R; both of these sounds are uvular fricatives, approximants or trills, and Arabic "ghain" represents a uvular fricative or a velar fricative. I agree that it will probably be understood as an /r/ sound in English even though it's might not be a common pronunciation for native speakers.